# Any solution to roscore crash?

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, Im running ros fuerte and when I run roscore I get the following error. Has anyone found a solution to this. I tried updating ubuntu. It seems that there is no agreed upon solution for this problem. I would appreciate any help on this.

```
asctec@asctec-mastermind:~$ roscore
WARNING: unable to configure logging. No log files will be generated
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://asctec-mastermind:43141/
ros_comm version 1.8.11

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES

auto-starting new master
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[master]: started with pid [1984]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rosmaster", line 35, in <module>
    rosmaster.rosmaster_main()
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ros_comm-1.8.7-py2.7.egg/rosmaster/main.py", line 73, in rosmaster_main
    configure_logging()   
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ros_comm-1.8.7-py2.7.egg/rosmaster/main.py", line 57, in configure_logging
    _log_filename = rosgraph.roslogging.configure_logging('rosmaster', logging.DEBUG, filename=filename)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ros_comm-1.8.7-py2.7.egg/rosgraph/roslogging.py", line 104, in configure_logging
    logging.config.fileConfig(config_file, disable_existing_loggers=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 78, in fileConfig
    handlers = _install_handlers(cp, formatters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 153, in _install_handlers
    klass = _resolve(klass)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 94, in _resolve
    __import__(used)
ImportError: No module named RosStreamHandler
[master] process has died [pid 1984, exit code 1, cmd rosmaster --core -p 11311 __log:=/home/asctec/.ros/log/504ce208-add8-11e1-a416-5bbefaef3a06/master.log].
log file: /home/asctec/.ros/log/504ce208-add8-11e1-a416-5bbefaef3a06/master*.log
ERROR: could not contact master [http://asctec-mastermind:11311/]
[master] killing on exit
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61454/any-solution-to-roscore-crash?/) by [tgaaly](https://answers.ros.org/users/2200/tgaaly/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2013-04-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-04-23**:
NO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-04-26**:
@Thomas it's not his.

**Comment by [Pino](https://answers.ros.org/users/4831/pino/) on 2013-09-30**:
This didn't solve the problem for me, but the solution by Amishandroid did.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please do not post questions with title in capital answers. It is considered as being rude on the internet.

It seems that the Python module `RosStreamHandler`  was not found. Did you source `/opt/ros/fuerte/setups.sh` before attempting to launch `roscore`?

Did you install ROS on Ubuntu using the precompiled binary package? Can you try to update just to be on the safe side? It seems I have a newer version of ros_comm on my machine.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2013-04-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran into this exact problem for everyone out there still having this problem here is how to fix it.

```
cd /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
ls
```

You should see something like "ros_comm-1.8.7-py2.7.egg" and "ros_comm-1.8.16.egg-info". The problem is that it believes "ros_comm-1.8.7-py2.7.egg" is the latest version probably because it compares the two string character by character to fix this either remove the older file.

```
sudo rm -r ros_comm-1.8.7-py2.7.egg
```

or rename the file

```
sudo mv ros_comm-1.8.7-py2.7.egg ros_comm-1.8.7-py2.7.egg.old
```

Now roscore should work. No dist-upgrade or re-install required.

---

Originally posted by [Amishandroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/5065/amishandroid/) with karma: 21 on 2013-06-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-06-05**:
This is a really bad idea; those files are supposed to be managed by the package manager. Doing a dist-upgrade is the preferred solution.

**Comment by [Amishandroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/5065/amishandroid/) on 2013-06-05**:
I am sorry you feel that way however for this case doing a dist-upgrade would remove all other older packages as well as update every package. Doing this in my case on the asctec mastermind this would result in more problems then it would fix.